# Can "Then" be used at the beginning of a sentence like " And"?

Tags: adverbs

> This device includes components A and B. A has element c and d. **Then,** B
> has element e and f.

I would like to know whether Then" in the sentence above I created is used correctly.  You may think "Then" in the sentence above is unnecessary, but I am required to translate literally, word by word, from my language to English.

Comment: Who or what is requiring you to translate literally word by word?  That is usually a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "Then" **can** be used at the start of a sentence, but it **is** unnecessary here. Unnecessary words often obscure the meaning. Translating word for word isn't always possible.

What do you want "[then](https://www.lexico.com/definition/then)" to mean? In this context it might mean:

"After that, B has..."
 or
 "Therefore, B has..."

But I don't think you want to say either of those things. So the sentence is incorrect.

We would usually say,

> A has elements c and d. B has elements e and f.

Note that "elements" is plural.

Comment: I want "Then" to mean simply "And".

Comment: But you don't *need* either "then" or "and". Those words spoil it. This is perfectly good English: "John has an apple. Mary has a banana." So is "A has elements c and d. B has elements e and f."